# will it possible to make docker mount with variable path or fix path is required?

Tags: docker, docker-volume, mounted-volumes

Currently I am mounting https certificate for docker/container with below Windows machine path 'C:\Users\user.aspnet`.

```
volumes:
  - ~/.aspnet/https:/app/certs:ro
```

I want to change the location of and want to keep the https certificate (`https`) within the source code directory.

```
\\[Base_Path]\src\https
```

For user A, Base_Path = C:\Repos\app
For user B, Base_Path = C:\Code\application\app, etc.

Question is, will it be possible to mount the files which satisfy all the users? Or I need to fix a path for file mount (C:/https) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compose [`volumes:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes) can use relative paths.  The path is interpreted relative to the location of the `docker-compose.yml` file.  If you use multiple `docker-compose -f` options, the path is interpreted relative to the location of the first Compose file, even if this one is in a different directory.

The setup you describe is quite common.  IME it's actually a little unusual to use an absolute path as the host directory for a bind mount, exactly because different users will have different home directories but the layout of the source-controlled repository will be the same everywhere.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the solution for my case? My `docker-compose.yml` is within `src` folder

Comment: You can `build: ..` to point at a parent directory, or `volumes: [../https:/app/certs]`.  (Within a Dockerfile you're somewhat limited but that's not this situation.)  You can also move the Compose file up to the root of your repository to simplify things somewhat.

Comment: Perfect. for me this work `./https:/app/certs`, single dot :)